# How can I automatically import a certificate to a Windows GPO?

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, active-directory, group-policy

I'm looking for a way to import a root certificate into a specific active directory group policy object. I've tried `certutil -dspublish` but that would only publish it to a global AD store.

How can I automatically import a certificate to a Windows GPO by using *vbs/powershell* or any other automatic way?

Answer (score 0):

Create or edit the Group Policy Object.

Navigate to `Computer Configuration, Windows Settings, Security Settings, Public Key Policies`.

Right click on `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` and select `Import`.

Import the certificate file.

You may have to run `gpupdate` on one of the intended clients to check the certificates replicated successfully, or wait a while for this to happen automatically.

Comment: This does not answer the question. I already know how to do it the manual way from the management console. I was asking if there is a way to do it from a script automatically.